# Local variables in function constructors

Tags: javascript, constructor, javascript-objects

In the below code,

```
function BaseClass(){
  var _localVar = 1;
  this.prop1 = _localVar;
}

function DerivedClass(){
   BaseClass.call(this);
   this.prop2 = 2;
}

var obj1 = new BaseClass();
var obj2 = new BaseClass();
var obj3 = new DerivedClass();

console.log(obj1.prop1);
console.log(obj2.prop1);
console.log(obj3.prop1);
```

---

Does `obj1`,`obj2` and `obj3` have its own copy of `_localVar`?

Comment: The ES standard does not define the "private member" term. One is a local variable, the other is the object property. The local variable will be declared and initialised every time a function/constructor is invoked.

Comment: @zerkms Query edited

Comment: And it's answered already. It's not obvious what made you thinking that local variables outlive the functions they are declared/used in.

Comment: @zerkms yes your first comment answered my question

Answer (score 1):

Each object's constructor has its own copy of `_localVar` as it is just a local variable inside a function scope so each time the function is executed a new local variable is created, but the way you have your code constructed, it is used once in the constructor, copied to a member property and then never referred to again for that particular constructor instance.

If you did something like this, then you could see how each one was different and lasted the lifetime of the object:

```
function BaseClass(val){
  var _localVar = val;
  this.getValue = function() {return _localVar};
  this.setValue = funciton(newVal) {_localVar = newVal;}
}

var x = new BaseClass(1);
var y = new BaseClass(2);
console.log(x.getValue());    // 1    
console.log(y.getValue());    // 2

x.setValue(10);
console.log(x.getValue());    // 10    
console.log(y.getValue());    // 2
```

Comment: so the `DerivedClass` has something like - `BaseClass.call(this,val);`?

Comment: @overexchange - `DerivedClass` is irrelevant to this particular issue.  But, yes if you are going to pass an argument on to the base constructor, then you would  do `BaseClass.call(this,val);`.

Comment: I use local variables in a way, as shown [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115239/37254). I dont pass parameters to function constructors because it breaks encapsulation

Comment: @overexchange - You have me confused why you think arguments to constructors break encapsulation in any way.  I've never had that issue in all my years of OO coding.

Comment: `Animal('11','22','33','44')` invokes with wrong arguments. So, I use interfaces to set the local variable. Your `BaseClass` has the same problem with `_localVar`, because `_localVar` can be assigned any illegal value.

Comment: @overexchange - All functions in Javascript can be called with wrong arguments.  The language does not protect you against that.  That is no different with a constructor or a method or a regular function.  I'm still not sure how avoiding constructor argumentw helps you in this regard and it sure limits the usefulness of creating objects with initial, non-default state without having to call additional methods to actually initialize the object.

Comment: @overexchange - Getting back on the topic of your original question - Have I answered it?

Comment: yes, you and zerkms have answered my original question.